# Stretching <li> to fill a horizontal Nav menu, within a 960 grid 12 col

Tags: html, css

Im trying to stretch the individual "li" elements within the "nav" element to fill the space that is 600px as defined in the HTML by the class="grid_8" in the  that houses the "ul" Ive tried putting width:100%; in the nav, li { width: 100%;} and some various forms of that solution.  No avail.  I look to you masters!

```
<div class="container_12 clearfix" >
    <div class="grid_4">
<!--logo--> <a href="index.html" alt="Above The Frey - Home page"> <img alt="Above The Frey - Home page" src="images/newLogo.png" /> </a>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_8">
                <nav>
<!-- navigation-->  <ul id="nav">

                    <li> <a href="schedule.html" >Schedule</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="schedule.html" >Portfolio</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="schedule.html" >Conntact</a> </li>
                    <li class="stretch"></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

    </div>
</div>


<!--video Container-->

<div class="container_12" id="videoContainer">

<iframe id="videoBorder" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fEJOYp3ciD0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>



</html>




Body {
background-image: url("images/background.jpg");

}
#nav
{
padding:0;
background-color: #333333;
text-align: justify;
}
#nav li 
{

display:inline;
width:100%;
width: 33%;
text-align: center;
}
#nav li a 
{   

   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   background-color: #333333;
   color:#ffffff;
   border-bottom:1px;
   border-bottom-color:#000000;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
   margin-top: 100px;
}

#nav li a:hover 
{
   background-color:#9B1C26;
   padding-bottom:12px;
   border-bottom:2px;
   border-bottom-color:#000000;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
   margin: 0px;
   margin-top: 100px;
}

#nav.stretch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;

     /* if you need IE6/7 support */
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

 #videoContainer 
{
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    padding: 20px;


}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nav {width:100%}`,`ul#nav {width:100%}`,`ul#nav li {width:100%}`
I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

check this out maybe helpful for what you want

```
.grid_8{
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#nav
{
    background-color: #333333;
    text-align: justify;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    height:39px;
}
#nav li 
{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;

}
#nav li a 
{   
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   background-color: #333333;
   color:#ffffff;
   vertical-align:bottom;
}

#nav li a:hover 
{
   background-color:#9B1C26;
   padding-bottom:12px;
   border-bottom:2px;
   border-bottom-color:#000000;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
   margin: 0px;

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRQE4/1/)